# Chrome extension content script without button in toolbar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a simple chrome extension that injects javascript into a specific site.
So i looked up the docs for chrome extensions and came up with this simple manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
      "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

So i went to chrome://extensions , activated developer mode and chose "load unpacked extension". Everything went as planned (code gets executed when i visit the site), except that i now got an button for the extension in the toolbar (like if i specified a browser_action in the manifest).
The documentation says:

```
// Pick one (or none)
"browser_action": {...},
"page_action": {...},
```

I obviously chose none, so why do i get that button and how can i prevent / fix it?

Comment: You can do nothing about it, because Google.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate. They should point that fact out somewhere visible in the docs. I'm completely fine with them wanting to protect the user, but they could've protected my nerves too.